# Python, inputting a command into an open CMD

Tags: python-3.x, cmd

I am attempting to create a program which will read an email, depending on the email's contents it will run a command. I have got the e-mail section working, all I need to know is how I would input this into a CMD that is already running.

If anyone can link me to a similar question or answer my question I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be an opened command line interface or would it be sufficient to execute another program?

Executing a subprocess can be done with:

```
from subprocess import call
call(['ps'])
```

yields for me (on linux) the output of the ps command. More about the call method can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call

hope this helps ^^-d

Comment: Well to be more specific I want it to manage various servers away from home, so I don't think this is applicable here. Thanks though

Comment: Hm i do not see a big difference between running a program and inputting a command into an open CMD. You could also run 'dir' or whatever you want. ^^

Comment: For and example, I'm running a minecraft server, I want to tell the server to run the command /killall, how would i do this using the subprocess module? I don't really understand it.

Comment: replace call(['ps']) with call(['killall', 'minecraft']) or in general call(['command','with','some','parameters']) - so yes this is exactly what you want ;)

Comment: What exactly should i replace minecraft with, the location of the launch file? Or the directory of the CMD itself? Just putting minecraft doesn't work.

Comment: Hi again, i think this is a seperate question ;) - the program needs the rights to run the command. For me both versions, calling the command only or giving absolute path to the command is working. If i try to enter /root as user `call(['cd','/root'])` i get OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory and bash: cd: /root: Permission denied in bash.

Comment: For setting up a minecraft server see here: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server - i have no experience with minecraft, but you need to run `java -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui` - i would just put that in a file called "runsiddonsminecraft" in /usr/bin/ or so and start this file via `call(['runsiddonsminecraft'])`. Hope this helps ^^-d

Comment: It will be easier to get the minecraft server to run first and then adding the specific command and its path (maybe) to the python code. Happy coding!